# Is there a way to auto generate poster image for videos

Tags: plugins, images, uploads, videos

I'm trying to have the poster auto generated for my videos so I don't have to keep taking screen shots of the first frame and manually adding it myself. Is there a way to do this? Reason is because video shows the 1st frame for desktop but doesn't show for mobile so I need to always manually add a poster image and its annoying!

Comment: This is more of a general question than WordPress related issue. Try searching for auto video thumbnailer

Comment: @Abhik well wordpress doesn't help with poster images so it kinda is a wordpress related issue

Comment: @Guest3000, check [this](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) out if you haven't already done so.

Comment: If you're actually uploading the videos (as opposed to just embedding links to externally hosted videos) then you should be able to hook the media library to do this, at the same place that it generates resized versions of uploaded images. It is a bit more complicated for videos though in that you don't always want the very first frame since that can be the lead in to a title card and blank.